# jQuery: Obtain the exact position of a DIV in pixels instead of getting back "auto" as the result

Tags: jquery, position

Let's say I have 5 `div`**vary in height and width** with `float:left;`:

When I use `.css("");` to get their positions (left & right),

`"auto"` would always end up be the result.

Any method to get the exact number **(left & right)** in pixels relative to the container (
**`position:absolute;`)**?

(*there are possibilities that the `div` would start a new row as I use `float:left;` and their widths and heights are undeterminable.*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has two methods for positions, one relative to document, and one relative to container.

[Relative to container (position)](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

[Relative to document (offset)](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

Note that position says relative to offset parent, so you might have to apply position: relative to the container element.